# how to make function to delete data from db

Tags: php, function, sql-delete

can any body tell me that how can i make function of this query in PHP that's why whenever i want it i just call a function to delete record. i am new in coding. please suggest simplest code to write function for this.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $query= "DELETE FROM student WHERE id='".$_GET['delete']."'";
    global $db;

   $row = $db->exec($query);
}

$query= "SELECT * FROM student";

global $db;
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$result = $result;
?>
```

Comment: global $db is a No-Go

Comment: i don't got what you said. please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    deleteStudent($_GET['delete']);
}

$query= "SELECT * FROM student";

global $db;
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$result = $result;

function deleteStudent($id) {
    global $db;
    $query= "DELETE FROM student WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $row = $db->exec($query);
    return $row; // expects it return the succes/failure flags properly.
} ?>
```